# Trying to convert base class object (array) to subclass using dynamic_cast but didn't work out

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm creating this question because I can't find any related solutions in dynamic_cast of object array on web, or just because I did not understand the concept of it, please lead me, Thank you

I'm currently working on a assignment which I have to use dynamic_cast to cast base class object (pointer) into it's subclasses object, to have access to others method in subclasses.

First of all I'll have this array
`Hardware *object = new Hardware[100];`

When it comes to need for access to subclasses of `Hardware` , I think I should do something like this: 
`Desktop *temp = dynamic_cast<Desktop*>(&object[0]);`

But the `temp` resulting in NULL pointer

I asked some friend and they said I'll have to do something like
`object[0] = new Desktop(//arguments);`

Then only I can proceed to `dynamic_cast of object[0]`, but it shows error(red lines) on the `=` operator :
 `no operator "=" matches these operands  operand types are: Hardware = Desktop *`

At the end I've tried many that similar to `object[0] = new Desktop(//arguments);` But didn't worked out, is there any steps that I've missed?

```
class Hardware //This is the base class
{
private:
   string code;
   double price;
public:
   Hardware();
   Hardware(string a, double b){ 
   code = a;
   price = b;
   }
virtual void foo(){}
}

class Laptop: public Hardware //More of subclasses like this
{
private:
   string brand;
public:
   Laptop();
   Laptop(string a, string b, double c):Hardware(b, c) { 
   brand = a;
   }
}

int main(){

//Have to create one base class object with ptr array
Hardware *object = new Hardware[100];

//friend suggest: object[0] = new Desktop("Acer", "COMP-001", 1200.00);

//I wanted to use dynamic_cast like this
Desktop *temp = dynamic_cast<Desktop*>(&object[0]);

//To access to subclasses method and constructor
temp->displayLaptop();


}
```

Expecting results that I can downcast the `Hardware class` into `Subclass Desktop`, and be able to assign arguments into `Desktop's constructor`

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it is incorrect.  The types stored in the `object` array are of type `Hardware`.  You can only successfully `dynamic_cast` those values to `Hardware` or anything that `Hardware` *inherits* (which is nothing).

Assuming `Desktop` is a subclass of `Hardware` (you did not actually show it), then `dynamic_cast<Desktop*>(&object[0])` is guaranteed to return `nullptr`.

The way arrays work is they allocate memory to store a specific data type arranged sequentially in memory.  You cannot expect to just treat that data type as a derived type that might (and in your case, *does*) contain more data.

If you wish to have an array of arbitrary hardware items, you will need to store each item as a pointer:

```
Hardware** object = new Hardware*[100];
std::fill(object, object + 100, NULL);
object[0] = new Desktop;
```

Your friend was correct, but you failed to change the type of `object` to store pointer types.  That's what the compiler error is telling you.

At this stage, I highly recommend you use `std::vector` instead of allocating and managing that memory:

```
std::vector<Hardware*> object(100);
object[0] = new Desktop;
```

Even better still, use smart pointers:

```
// Example with shared pointers
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hardware>> object;
object.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Desktop>(/* args */));

// Example with unique pointers
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Hardware>> object;
object.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Desktop>(/* args */));
```

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood what dynamic casting does.

Example of use:
Say you have two classes Square and Circle and both of them inherit from class Shape.

A producer creates either a Square or a Circle but passes you a pointer to a Shape.

Then via dynamic casting you can try and convert the pointer to Shape to a pointer Circle. If the Producer made a Square then the casting will fail return `nullptr`. If it was indeed a Circle then you will get a pointer to Circle.

In your case you create Shape and try to use dynamic casting to convert the pointer to a Square... it doesn't work this way.